# red bean php find by relation

Tags: php, redbean

This seems like a simple question, but I'm somehow baffled.

If I create a couple of beans with:

```
list($product1, $product2, $product3) = R::dispense('product', 3);
...
```

and a couple of categories with:

```
list($cat1, $cat2) = R::dispense('category', 2);
...
```

then link them with:

```
$product1->sharedCategory[] = $cat1;
$product3->sharedCategory[] = $cat1;
```

how do I then query all products that are related to $cat1? I should get back product 1 and 3.

Like I said, simple. In mysql this is a no-brainer, so could always just send red bean an sql string, but there must be a way of doing this built it, surely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it goes the other way around (sorry if I am not right) because logically a category has many products not a product many categories as you have defined it.

========Edited part====================

I deleted a small source posted here because the manual [Manuall](http://redbeanphp.com/downloads/redbean.pdf)
is super easy and much better and very helpful with sample code on how to connect, make association, updates etc etc. I am sure you will benefit a lot from it. If there is any difficulty with the manual glad to help.

========== Additional Information =======================

Here I just put some source code, did not change anything in my answear. Try this code, it works both ways as you want it!

```
<?PHP
echo '<pre>';

require('rb.php'); 
$toolbox = R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_ORM','root','');
$farm = R::dispense('building');

//create the product list
list($product1,$product2,$product3) = R::dispense('product',3);
//add attributes 
$product1->name='prod1';
$product2->name='prod2';
$product3->name='prod3';


//create a list of categories 
list($category1,$category2) = R::dispense('category',2);
//add attributes 
$category1->name='categ1';
$category2->name='categ2';

//the connect beans together
R::associate($category1,$product1);
R::associate($category1,$product2);
R::associate($category1,$product3);
R::associate($category2,$product3);

//then store
R::store($product1);
R::store($product2);
R::store($product3);
R::store($category1);
R::store($category2); 

//get id for category 1
$categId=R::getCell( " select  `id` from `category` where `name`='categ1'  ");
//get products for category 1
$results = 
R::getAll( "
SELECT  `product`.`id`,`product`.`name` 
FROM `product`  left JOIN `category_product`
on `category_product`.`product_id`= `product`.`id` 
where  `category_id`='".$categId."' ");
//display
print_r($results);

//get categories for product3
$prodId=R::getCell( " select  `id` from `product` where `name`='prod3'  ");
$results = 
R::getAll( "
SELECT  `category`.`id`,`category`.`name` 
FROM `category`  left JOIN `category_product`
on `category_product`.`category_id`= `category`.`id` 
where  `product_id`='".$prodId."' ");
print_r($results);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're right, that is a more logical heirarcical structure. But I need it to work both ways. My terminology is wrong; "tag" might be a better term than "category". If I do it your way then the question becomes: "how do I query all categories for a single product?"

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for taking the time to put that together.